# PHP pass a variable to Class and use it as prefix for constant or variable

Tags: php

I have set a global variable $lang ($lang = 'de'), is there a way how I could get "Hallo!" by using, I'm using PHP 7.3:

```
L::HELLO('Mike');?
```

I'm not looking for a solution like:

```
sprintf(constant('L::' . $lang . '_HELLO'), 'Mike');
```

instead to got them by calling only:

```
L::HELLO('Mike');
```

or:

```
L::HI;
```

actual Class (I can change const by var if this would help or initiate class with set language):

```
<?php class L {
    const en_HELLO = 'Hello %s!';
    const de_HELLO = 'Hallo %s!';
    const fr_HELLO = 'Bonjour %s!';
    const it_HELLO = 'Ciao %s!';
    const en_HI = 'Hi...';
    const de_HI = 'Hi...';
    const fr_HI = 'Hi...';
    const it_HI = 'Hi...';

    public static function __callStatic($string, $args) {
        return vsprintf(constant("self::" . $string), $args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the `vsprintf(constant('L::' . $lang . '_HELLO'), 'Mike');`?

Comment: @Damian Dziaduch I'm using this in various templates and this would invole huge work to change it on all places, aside that the other way is better readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways I can see for this.  The first is the simplest - but also I would normally not recommend it.

This uses `global` to allow you to access the variable you already have and includes it as part of the key used to display the constant...

```
public static function __callStatic($string, $args) {
    global $lang;
    return vsprintf(constant("self::" .$lang."_" . $string), $args);
}
```

So

```
$lang = "de";
echo L::HELLO('Mike');
```

gives

```
Hallo Mike!
```

The second method involves setting the language into your class, so it's an extra step, but it's also more flexible (IMHO)...

```
class L {
    const en_HELLO = 'Hello %s!';
    const de_HELLO = 'Hallo %s!';
    const fr_HELLO = 'Bonjour %s!';
    const it_HELLO = 'Ciao %s!';

    protected static $lang = "en";

    public static function setLang ( string $lang )  {
        self::$lang = $lang;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($string, $args) {
        return vsprintf(constant("self::" .self::$lang."_" . $string), $args);
    }
}
```

So then you use it as...

```
$lang = "de";
L::setLang($lang);
echo L::HELLO('Mike');
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried both solutions, but it fails and I got all the time Undefined class constant 'HELLO'. Any idea why this happen?

Comment: I have tried the code in the last example and had no problems getting the result, have you tried using the exact code I've shown above?

Comment: You're right it was my fault, it work's with above, I have some constant without argument like en_HI = 'Hi!'; there it won't work, do you probably know why?

Comment: Can you show the code which is not working for you (preferably in the question), I've tried a few things but  not found anything.

Comment: I have updated my sample in the question, I can now use L::HI(), L::en_HI but I can not L::HI; is there a solution that I can get it by L::HI;?

Comment: I've had a look and it doesn't look as though there is anything you can do to shorted it (missing out the `()`).